# How to check if an image is already present locally

Tags: java, docker, docker-java

I am using the [docker-java](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java) Maven library, and I would like to know if there is a way to check if an image has already been pulled or is present locally before pulling it if necessary, with only the image name.
Currently, I have to pull the image everytime I execute it to ensure it is present locally, which is not nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to do it in Java, you can use the `inspectImageCmd` method of the `com.github.dockerjava.api.DockerClient` interface. Then check the returned `InspectImageResponse` response object. Something like this:

```
String imageId = ...;
InspectImageResponse response = dockerClient.inspectImageCmd(imageid).exec();
```

`docker-java` is just a wrapper for the Docker REST API and the inspect command is the equivalent of the `GET` http request to `/images/{imageid}/json`. See section *3.2 Images* in [Docker Engine API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/).

Comment: With this method I have to catch an exception: com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.NotFoundException which is not very clean imo but it might be the only way...

Comment: I don't like it either but that's how the library works. The REST call returns a `404 (Not Found)` HTTP response if the image does not exist which is translated into a `NotFoundException`.

Comment: Glad it helped.